# Can't create account using trigger

Tags: trigger, web2lead

What I was originally trying to do (create an account for each lead as it was created):

```
trigger LeadCreateAccount on Lead (Before Insert) {
    Public List<Account> lstAccts = new List<Account>();
    Public List<Account> lstNewAccts = new List<Account>();
    Public set<String> setLeadNames = new set<String>();
    Public set<String> setExistingAcctNames = new set<String>();
    public String name = '';

    // Create the set for al the names of the leads
    for(Lead l: trigger.new)
    {
        setLeadNames.add(l.firstname + ' ' + l.lastname);
    }

    // fetch the matching accounts if any exists
    lstAccts = [select id,name from account where name IN : setLeadNames];

    for(Account a: lstAccts)
    {
        setExistingAcctNames.add(a.name);
    }

    // Iterate through all leads to create acocunt if it does nto exists
    for(Lead l: trigger.new)
    {
        name = l.firstname + ' ' + l.lastname;
        if (! setExistingAcctNames.contains(name))
        {
            Account acct = new account();
            acct.name = name;
            // MAP ALL THE FIELDS U WANT TO MAP HERE
            lstNewAccts.add(acct);

            // Add this to avoid any duplication in current set fo leads
            setExistingAcctNames.add(name);
        }

    }

    if (lstNewAccts.size() > 0)
        insert lstNewAccts;
}
```

This didn't work though, so I tried something simpler:

```
trigger LeadCreateAccount on Lead (Before Insert) {

            Account acct = new account();
            acct.name = 'asdf';

            insert acct;
}
```

If I use a system.debug() log then it shows up in my debug logs, but no account ever gets created with either piece of code. They're both definitely triggered when a lead is created though because the debug message works.

What am I doing wrong here?

EDIT:
Here's my debug log:

```
31.0 APEX_CODE,DEBUG;APEX_PROFILING,INFO;CALLOUT,INFO;DB,INFO;SYSTEM,DEBUG;VALIDATION,INFO;VISUALFORCE,INFO;WORKFLOW,INFO
12:35:17.059 (59411704)|EXECUTION_STARTED
12:35:17.059 (59448789)|CODE_UNIT_STARTED|[EXTERNAL]|TRIGGERS
12:35:17.059 (59491218)|CODE_UNIT_STARTED|[EXTERNAL]|01qe00000004a07|LeadCreateAccount on Lead trigger event BeforeInsert for [new]
12:35:17.147 (147465285)|CODE_UNIT_STARTED|[EXTERNAL]|Workflow:Account
12:35:17.169 (169830325)|CODE_UNIT_FINISHED|Workflow:Account
12:35:17.382 (170640617)|CUMULATIVE_LIMIT_USAGE
12:35:17.382|CUMULATIVE_LIMIT_USAGE_END

12:35:17.170 (170695438)|CODE_UNIT_FINISHED|LeadCreateAccount on Lead trigger event BeforeInsert for [new]
12:35:17.192 (192314341)|CODE_UNIT_STARTED|[EXTERNAL]|Validation:Lead:new
12:35:17.192 (192327943)|VALIDATION_RULE|03d40000000Gy27|Lead_Type
12:35:17.192 (192620384)|VALIDATION_FORMULA|AND(
  OR(
    ISPICKVAL( Primary_Contact_Type__c , "Arch"), 
    ISPICKVAL( Primary_Contact_Type__c, "Cont")
  ),
  ISBLANK(Company)
)|Primary_Contact_Type__c=null , Company=fdsfasdf
12:35:17.192 (192631693)|VALIDATION_PASS
12:35:17.192 (192634435)|VALIDATION_RULE|03d40000000H3Wa|Salesforce
12:35:17.192 (192907646)|VALIDATION_FORMULA|IF(RecordType.Id = "01240000000M72r", IF(NOT(ISPICKVAL( Status ,"lost to others"))  && NOT(ISPICKVAL( Status , "lost: project killed")) && NOT(ISPICKVAL( Status , "Disqualified")),True,False)

,False)|Status=Qualifying , RecordType.Id=01240000000M6kH
12:35:17.192 (192918240)|VALIDATION_PASS
12:35:17.192 (192936229)|CODE_UNIT_FINISHED|Validation:Lead:new
12:35:17.290 (290323193)|CODE_UNIT_STARTED|[EXTERNAL]|Workflow:Lead
12:35:17.299 (299467432)|WF_RULE_EVAL_BEGIN|Workflow
12:35:17.299 (299501880)|WF_CRITERIA_BEGIN|[Lead: fdsaf 00Qe0000003fQPO]|Auto-Notify-New-Web-To-Lead|01Q40000000VIL5|ON_CREATE_ONLY
12:35:17.302 (302505007)|WF_RULE_FILTER|[Lead : Homeowner/Trade equals Web]
12:35:17.302 (302516120)|WF_RULE_EVAL_VALUE|
12:35:17.302 (302521098)|WF_CRITERIA_END|false
12:35:17.302 (302535891)|WF_SPOOL_ACTION_BEGIN|Workflow
12:35:17.302 (302543305)|WF_ACTION| None
12:35:17.302 (302546977)|WF_RULE_EVAL_END
12:35:17.302 (302596265)|WF_ACTIONS_END| None
12:35:17.302 (302603377)|CODE_UNIT_FINISHED|Workflow:Lead
12:35:17.379 (379352270)|CODE_UNIT_FINISHED|TRIGGERS
12:35:17.379 (379371588)|EXECUTION_FINISHED
```

Comment: note, in general, it is best to do related record DML in `after` triggers -- especially if you ever need to associate the related record SObject with the inserted SObject -- as ids are not known in the before trigger.  You are also guaranteed that if there were any validation errors on the insert, your after trigger won't be executed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try modifying your code as follows:

```
trigger LeadCreateAccount on Lead (Before Insert) {

            Account acct = new account();
            acct.name = 'asdf';
try {
            insert acct; 
}
catch (system.Dmlexception e) {
       system.debug (e);      
    }
system.debug (acct.id);    // it will print new account id to console   
}
```

This way you might find the error (say validation rule) that prevented insert. Alternatively, try Executing Anonymous (from Debug menu) code block without the first and last line.

Comment: see edits to post

Comment: Seems your code does not attempt to insert anything - probably there is flaw in logic. Try adding more system.debug() after each step and pretty quickly you will realize whats wrong.

Comment: There's not really anything else I can log out besides the name....

Comment: I feel like we are not on the same boat :) have you tried running my code and getting response? Also try running your code from execute anonymous with hardcoded names, it will save you time from going into debug monitoring.

Comment: That was the response from your code

Comment: Could the problem be that I don't have test cases?

Comment: No, it shouldn't. Test cases are only needed when you are deploying to production. I assume you are in Sandbox as otherwise you would not be able to edit code.

Comment: Yeah I'm in sandbox

Comment: Well there is nothing wrong with with the code. Are you sure it's not created? I've made an edit that should print newly created account ID into console. Try accessing that id using url: `YOURINSTANCE_like_CS16.salesforce.com/{that_ID_from_log}` Also try executing SOQL from Query Editor in Developer Console: `select id, name, createdDate from Account order by createddate limit 10`

Comment: What the heck... It shows up in the accounts list once I go to that url, but not until then

Comment: Oh my god I was on the recently viewed default setting, not recently created